# A small question about Vitali covering lemma proof.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The Lemma and the first part of its proof are given below:

> [image]

**My question is:**

I think the first line in the proof by the following part (i) in the following theorem  .... am I correct?

> [image]

if so, I have this question, why $E$ being any set of real numbers leads to that $m^{*}(E)$ is finite, can not $E$ be an infinite set of real numbers?

Comment: "Let $E$ be a set of finite outer measure" **means** "$m^*(E)<\infty$".

Comment: $E$ a set of finite measure does not imply measurability. So the lemma is not used. What is used is the definition of outer measure . Indeed, if we have a bunch of intervals covering $E$, they can be made to have total finite length, and their union can be taken as $O$.

Comment: by which theorem (in Royden 4th edition) you guarantee this @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: Let me see the book (I have it) and tell you.

Comment: Yes, I see in the definition of "outer measure" at the stare of the section on "outer measure" the following : $m^*(A)  = \inf_{A \subset \cup I_n} l(I_n)$ over all countable collections of open intervals $I_n$ covering $A$. So if $m^*(A) < \infty$ then for some collection $I_n$ this sum is finite. We take $O$ to be the union of all these $I_n$. Then $m^*(O)$ is less than the sum of all the lengths(same as outer measure for intervals) of $I_n$ ,and so is finite.

Comment: Can you please look at this question at the second answer (the 2 questions in the comments below it)? (if you do not mind)https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2994554/question-about-vitali-covering@астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so: in the theorem as stated there is no assumption that $E$ be measurable, and one would need that to apply theorem 11.

But that's not necessary. As $E$ has finite outer measure, there is a sequence
of open intervals $(I_n)$ covering $E$ of finite total length. Take
$\mathcal{O}=\bigcup_n I_n$.

Comment: by which theorem (in Royden 4th edition) you guarantee this ?

Comment: @Secretly What's the _defiinition_ of "$E$ has finite outer measure"?